# Openssl_encrypt makes text not suitable to send via GET in URL to a php

Tags: php, encryption, get, openssl

I've developed an Android app using my company's active directory user/password to login.
When the user enters his credentials, the password is encrypted and I send the info to a php file using GET method. 
Recently a user cound't log in and I think it was due to a '+' symbol on the ecrypted password.

I tried disabling the ecryption and he could log in. So thats the problem for sure.

This is the code I use to encrypt the data:

```
function encrypt_new($data) {
    $OPENSSL_CIPHER_NAME = "aes-128-cbc"; //Name of OpenSSL Cipher 
    $CIPHER_KEY_LEN = 16;
    $iv = 'fedcba9876543210';
    $key = '0123456789abcdef';

    if (strlen($key) < $CIPHER_KEY_LEN) {
        $key = str_pad("$key", $CIPHER_KEY_LEN, "0"); //0 pad to len 16
    }

    $encryptedData = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($data, $OPENSSL_CIPHER_NAME, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv));

    return $encryptedData;
}
```

The resulting URL with this specific user is:

```
login.php?user=someuser&pwd=r+FjjfugRQXlcURU8eMOCQ==
```

What can I do about it? change the encryption method? How can I be sure that won't happen again?

Comment: look like  `url_encode()` is what you want to us

Comment: Except that you should not be passing passwords about anyway. Instead change the server to use ssl (https) and then everything will get encrypted in transit

Comment: Yes! `url_encode` fixed it! I know sending passwords like that is bad practice, I'll be looking into improving security. Thank you so much, I was going crazy.